# Passing a function through list of columns with numpy.vectorize or DataFrame.apply?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply

I've got the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'Product_JP': ['ﾄﾏﾄｺ- ｻﾙｻ C225G','ﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟ','ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊﾞﾘﾕ-','ｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊ-ﾌ','ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾌﾟﾚﾐｱﾑ'],
                  'Value1': [1,12313,1.123,0.112,0],
                  'Metric1_JP': ['ﾏ-ｹｯﾄｻｲｽﾞ(販売金額(x1000))','加重販売率(販売金額)','ｱｲﾃﾑ販売店当り(販売個数)','加重販売率(販売金額)','加重販売率(販売金額)'],
                  'Type_JP': ['サルサソ−ス','ケチャップ','ケチャップ','ケチャップ','ケチャップ'],
                  'SKU': [4582152498325,4582112498325,4500152498325,4582112398325,4582152483125]},
                 )


        Product_JP     Value1              Metric1_JP Type_JP            SKU
0  ﾄﾏﾄｺ- ｻﾙｻ C225G      1.000  ﾏ-ｹｯﾄｻｲｽﾞ(販売金額(x1000))  サルサソ−ス  4582152498325
1         ﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟ  12313.000             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582112498325
2   ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊﾞﾘﾕ-      1.123         ｱｲﾃﾑ販売店当り(販売個数)   ケチャップ  4500152498325
3        ｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊ-ﾌ      0.112             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582112398325
4  ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾌﾟﾚﾐｱﾑ      0.000             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582152483125
```

And I can apply the following function using `df.apply()`

```
from deep_translator import (GoogleTranslator)
df['Product_EN'] = df['Product_JP'].apply(lambda row:GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='en').translate(row))

        Product_JP     Value1              Metric1_JP Type_JP            SKU  \
0  ﾄﾏﾄｺ- ｻﾙｻ C225G      1.000  ﾏ-ｹｯﾄｻｲｽﾞ(販売金額(x1000))  サルサソ−ス  4582152498325   
1         ﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟ  12313.000             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582112498325   
2   ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊﾞﾘﾕ-      1.123         ｱｲﾃﾑ販売店当り(販売個数)   ケチャップ  4500152498325   
3        ｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊ-ﾌ      0.112             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582112398325   
4  ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾌﾟﾚﾐｱﾑ      0.000             加重販売率(販売金額)   ケチャップ  4582152483125   

             Product_EN  
0  Tomatoco-Salsa C225G  
1               Matthew  
2          Tomato miser  
3                 Catch  
4  Tomato miser premium
```

But what I want to do is to pass a list of columns to apply in one go like so

```
JP_columns = [column for column in df.columns if '_JP' in column]
EN_columns = [column.replace('_JP', '_EN') for column in JP_columns]

df[EN_columns] = df[JP_columns].apply(lambda row:GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='en').translate(row))
```

This returns a ValueError: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

1. What am I doing wrong with `df.apply()`
2. Would this be better done using `np.vectorize`?

for example (Also returns a Value Error: "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous")

```
df[EN_columns] = np.vectorize(GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='en').translate(df[JP_columns]))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) applies the function to each cell (row) in the Series since there is a single dimension. However, [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) passes the entire column to the function by default. However, `translate` expects `text` not a collection.

The function to apply a function to each cell in a DataFrame is [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and can be used as such:

```
JP_columns = [column for column in df.columns if '_JP' in column]
EN_columns = [column.replace('_JP', '_EN') for column in JP_columns]

# apply to all cells in the DataFrame
df[EN_columns] = df[JP_columns].applymap(
    GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='en').translate
)
```

---

[`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) can also work, note it takes a `pyfunc` as input in this case `translate` and returns a `callable`:

```
JP_columns = [column for column in df.columns if '_JP' in column]
EN_columns = [column.replace('_JP', '_EN') for column in JP_columns]

# vectorize function then call function on DataFrame
df[EN_columns] = np.vectorize(
    GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='en').translate
)(df[JP_columns])
```

Either approach results in `df`:

| Product_JP | Value1 | Metric1_JP | Type_JP | SKU | Product_EN | Metric1_EN | Type_EN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ﾄﾏﾄｺ- ｻﾙｻ C225G | 1 | ﾏ-ｹｯﾄｻｲｽﾞ(販売金額(x1000)) | サルサソ−ス | 4582152498325 | Tomatoco-Salsa C225G | Market size (sales amount (x1000)) | Salsa source |
| ﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟ | 12313 | 加重販売率(販売金額) | ケチャップ | 4582112498325 | Matthew | Weighted sales rate (sales amount) | ketchup |
| ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊﾞﾘﾕ- | 1.123 | ｱｲﾃﾑ販売店当り(販売個数) | ケチャップ | 4500152498325 | Tomato miser | Per item store (number of units sold) | ketchup |
| ｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊ-ﾌ | 0.112 | 加重販売率(販売金額) | ケチャップ | 4582112398325 | Catch | Weighted sales rate (sales amount) | ketchup |
| ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾌﾟﾚﾐｱﾑ | 0 | 加重販売率(販売金額) | ケチャップ | 4582152483125 | Tomato miser premium | Weighted sales rate (sales amount) | ketchup |

---

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np  # only for np.vectorize
import pandas as pd
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product_JP': ['ﾄﾏﾄｺ- ｻﾙｻ C225G', 'ﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟ', 'ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊﾞﾘﾕ-', 'ｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾊ-ﾌ',
                   'ﾄﾏﾄｹﾁﾔﾂﾌﾟﾌﾟﾚﾐｱﾑ'],
    'Value1': [1, 12313, 1.123, 0.112, 0],
    'Metric1_JP': ['ﾏ-ｹｯﾄｻｲｽﾞ(販売金額(x1000))', '加重販売率(販売金額)',
                   'ｱｲﾃﾑ販売店当り(販売個数)', '加重販売率(販売金額)',
                   '加重販売率(販売金額)'],
    'Type_JP': ['サルサソ−ス', 'ケチャップ', 'ケチャップ', 'ケチャップ', 'ケチャップ'],
    'SKU': [4582152498325, 4582112498325, 4500152498325, 4582112398325,
            4582152483125]
})
```

Comment: It seems applymap is about the same/faster than vectorize on this sample
applymap: 18 s ± 93.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
vectorize: 19.1 s ± 64.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Which one is better to use? I have read different things about each, this is only a small sample from a larger dataframe of 3k+ rows and 60+ columns

Comment: There is almost no difference between them. The implementations are near identical. There's no real way around this for this particular task. You have to process every single cell individually. The only thing that would increase the speed are things like async/parallelization neither of which are provided within the defaults.

Comment: It seems that the largest portion of time is actually dedicated to the translation rather than the iteration. It may be faster to reduce the Series into a text block and call translate a single time. I'd suggest trying these out, and if it's not fast enough for your purposes open a new question about how to improve efficiency.